# C# How to programmatically export/save DBML diagram?

Tags: image, linq-to-sql, save, class-diagram

We work with many Linq to DB object models and every time there's a change we have to open the DBML design surface and save out the diagram image for doc purposes.

Is there a programmatic way of generating an image of the dbml and saving it to a JPG or some image format?

All I've seen is how to do this manually.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can export the diagram following the below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469815.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can "print" the DBML file to any virtual printer like Microsoft Document Image Writer which comes bundled with Microsoft Office Professional. This way you get an image file in TIFF format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know where I can get some code samples for doing this?